# Passing fstream to function as structure member

Tags: c++, fstream

I have following structure,

```
struct option
{   
    std::fstream fpointer;
    char* clifn;
};
```

I want to pass this structure as argument to another function (other way is to pass individual element and fpointer as reference), passing it to function throws a compiler error

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_fstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

is there any way to pass std::fstream object of struct member to function.

Comment: I guess you are passing `option` by value, you should pass it by reference. copy of fstream is disabled. And show us your function declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Streams are not copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) so `struct option` is therefore not copyable because it has a non-copyable member (`fpointer`). Pass `struct option` by reference to avoid the copy:

```
void some_function(option& a_option)
{
}
```